# Statistics about malware targeting different OS

Tags: malware, virus

Are there any reports or statistics that describe the numbers or types of malware attacks on different operating systems, such as Linux, Unix, Windows, MacOS?

Answer (score 6):

Most AV Vendors produce and publish information about malware statistics.

See [here](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/publications/threatreport.jsp) for Symantec and [here](http://www.mcafee.com/au/resources/reports/rp-quarterly-threat-q1-2013.pdf) for McAfee.
They also delve into detail about trends, Mobile malware and other findings through out the period.

Answer (score 1):

These Kaspersky has the easiest accessible statistics for OS. You don't have to download a PDF and browse through, and they get to the OS distribution pretty fast.

http://securelist.com/analysis/kaspersky-security-bulletin/58265/kaspersky-security-bulletin-2013-overall-statistics-for-2013/